# The type variable r has escaped its scope

Tags: purescript

I have a type synonym for a puzzle defined as shown here:

```purs
type Cell = Int
type Board = Array Cell

type Puzzle = forall r.
  { board::Board
  , meta::
    { metaData :: {|r}
    , metaBoard :: (Array {|r})
    }
  }
```

I have also included the idea that a strategy takes a Puzzle and returns it wrapped in one of three states

```purs
type Strategy = Puzzle -> (Stateful Puzzle)

data Stateful a =
  Advancing a
  | Stable a
  | Finished a
```

Finally, I have a function that brings us back in line (a bit) with how `Either` works. The idea being that eventually I can start composing strategies until the finished state is reached.

```purs
advanceOrFinish :: (Stateful Puzzle) -> (Stateful Puzzle)
advanceOrFinish (Advancing puzzle)
  | isSolvedOrInvalid puzzle.board = Finished puzzle
  | otherwise = Advancing puzzle
advanceOrFinish (Stable puzzle)
  | isSolvedOrInvalid puzzle.board = Finished puzzle
  | otherwise = Advancing puzzle
advanceOrFinish (Finished puzzle) = Finished puzzle
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```html
  The type variable r, bound at

    src/SC.purs:23:15 - 29:4 (line 23, column 15 - line 29, column 4)

  has escaped its scope, appearing in the type
                                              
    { board :: Array Int                      
    , meta :: { metaBoard :: Array (Record r7)
              , metaData :: Record r7         
              }                               
    }
```

The same function without `Stateful` (while useless) doesn't have this issue. So this is fine:

```purs
advanceOrFinish :: Puzzle -> Puzzle
advanceOrFinish puzzle
  | isSolvedOrInvalid puzzle.board = puzzle
  | otherwise = puzzle
```

---

What is this error trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type Puzzle = forall r. ...` doesn't mean what you think it means.

If you have a variable:

```
p :: Puzzle
```

And then you want to *do something* with that variable, like:

```
b = p.board
```

At that moment, when you're referring to `p` by name, you get to choose a type `r`, and then the variable `p` must somehow "become" of that type, meaning that `p.meta.metaData :: {|r}`.

And this happens *every time* you access the variable `p`. Each time you choose some type `r` (and these could be different types every time), and each time the field `p.meta.metaData` would have to be of that type.

Quite obviously, this could not reasonably work. Quite obviously, this is not what you meant.

`forall` means "I will work *for all* types" - that's literally in the name. The consumer chooses which type, not the implementer.

---

What you probably meant was to have a `Puzzle` with a type parameter, so that whoever creates an instance of `Puzzle` can choose the type at that moment, and then the instance of `Puzzle` will go on with that type.

The syntax for doing that is this:

```hs
type Puzzle r =
  { board::Board
  , meta::
    { metaData :: {|r}
    , metaBoard :: (Array {|r})
    }
  }
```

Here `r` is called "type parameter" of `Puzzle`.

Then, whenever you refer to `Puzzle`, you have to say what `r` is in that case, for example:

```hs
foo :: Puzzle (a :: Int) -> Int
foo p = p.meta.metaData.a

bar :: Puzzle (x :: String) -> Unit
bar _ = unit
```

And if you don't care what it is, it can be generic too:

```hs
advanceOrFinish :: forall r. Puzzle r -> Puzzle r
advanceOrFinish puzzle
  | isSolvedOrInvalid puzzle.board = puzzle
  | otherwise = puzzle
```

Comment: Can I type it to say that metaData is a record that can have any fields? Am I better off choosing a different data-structure instead? Metadata is meant to be unstructured, how it gets used is specific to the strategy being employed, so I'd want something that can store arbitrary key-value pairs. Records look sort of like JavaScript objects, but perhaps a `Map` is actually a better fit

Comment: For now, `metaData: {}` works, though I would think this only matches with explicitly empty records?

Comment: If you want a JS hash with arbitrary fields, [use `Foreign.Object.Object`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign-object/3.0.0/docs/Foreign.Object#t:Object) - that's literally implemented as a JS hash. Alternatively, you can [use a `Map`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-ordered-collections/2.0.0/docs/Data.Map.Internal#t:Map).

Comment: Ah, thanks, looks like exactly what I was after :)